# cocos2d-x What is the best way to use device orientation portrait and landscape

Tags: cocos2d-x

I scanned the forum and also in the test examples with no strict answer to the question
how can i support game portrait and landscape device orientation. on iOS first 
is there any kind of example or source or something i can see and learn 
thanks !

Comment: what you exactly want ... please explain in brief

Comment: i want to understand if there is pattern or something to code 
when the user rotate its device from portrait to  landscape
or from  landscape portrait how all the layers and sprites on the screen keep the aspect ratio and how to change the positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Device_Orientation

For ios : in viewcontroller.m

```
bool shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
```

// for Landscape

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation );
```

// for Potrait

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPotrait( interfaceOrientation );
```

}

if multiple :

```
bool shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

{

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)||UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation) ;
```

}

## Scaling Contents according to your Orientations :

```
void didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

CGSize s;
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation))
{
s = CGSizeMake(std::max<float>(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width,    UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height), 
                         std::min<float>(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width,  UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height));
} 
else
{
s = CGSizeMake(std::min<float>(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width,     UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height),  
                         std::max<float>(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height));
}

CCDirector* director = cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector();
director->enableRetinaDisplay(false);
director->getOpenGLView()->setFrameSize(s.width, s.height);
director->getOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(s.width, s.height, kResolutionShowAll);
director->enableRetinaDisplay(true);
```

Comment: yeah i know this , but i need so check solution that is dynamic 
when user rotate its device and i need to rotate all my layers and sprites coordinates or something ....

Comment: @user63898 ..  i understand .. for that you have to scale your contents according to your orientations .. you can achieve this  by  ContentScaleFactor & designResolutionsize .. . you can see this http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Multi_resolution_support  ..

Comment: @user63898 check my que & ans . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948382/multi-resolution-support-for-all-android-devices/18097650#18097650.....   this might help ..

Comment: Thanks for the replay , the cocos2d-x is not so good on answering questions , wander why it suppose to be full with masters

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
      bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
   {
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


 window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
EAGLView *__glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame: [window bounds]
                                 pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                 depthFormat: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16
                          preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                  sharegroup: nil
                               multiSampling: NO
                             numberOfSamples:0 ];

    // Use RootViewController manage EAGLView
     viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
     viewController.view = __glView;
   } 


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( interfaceOrientation );
   }
```